# Understanding x argument requirements in sub()

Tags: r, for-loop, replace

I have the following pieces of code where I wish to replace numbers (1,2,3,4) by letters (A,T,G,C) in a vector of length 20. I purposely want to use a for-loop, if-statement, and **sub()** as this is part of an exercise to show code (in)efficiency against **gsub()** and **which()**.

```
rand1M = round(runif(n = 20,min = 1,max = 4))

it = 1
for(i in rand1M) {
  if(i == 1) {
    rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "1", replacement = "A", x = i)
  }
  if(i == 2) {
    rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "2", replacement = "T", x = i)
  }
  if(i == 3) {
    rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "3", replacement = "G", x = i)
  }
  if(i == 4) {
    rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "4", replacement = "C", x = i)
  }
  it = it + 1
}
```

This code does what it's asked, and the result are complete substitutions of the numbers in the vector.

Following this, I tried to remove the if-statements as they feel a bit redundant considering **sub()** is already checking for the condition. And so:

```
rand1M = round(runif(n = 20,min = 1,max = 4))
it = 1
for(i in rand1M) {
    rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "1", replacement = "A", x = i)
    rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "2", replacement = "T", x = i)
    rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "3", replacement = "G", x = i)
    rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "4", replacement = "C", x = i)
  it = it + 1
}
```

The result, however, is that only the very last **sub()** works, so only letters C are replaced in the vector. Why is this happening?

Replacing "x=i" by "x=rand1M[it]" seems to do the trick but I can't understand why.

```
rand1M = round(runif(n = 20,min = 1,max = 4))
it = 1
for(i in rand1M) {
  rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "1", replacement = "A", x = rand1M[it])
  rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "2", replacement = "T", x = rand1M[it])
  rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "3", replacement = "G", x = rand1M[it])
  rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "4", replacement = "C", x = rand1M[it])
  it = it + 1
}
```

Thanks in advance for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying your code, it looks like this:

```
y <- sub("1", "A", x)
y <- sub("2", "T", x)
y <- sub("3", "G", x)
y <- sub("4", "C", x)
```

The value produced in the 2nd to 4th substitutions ignores the value produced in the earlier ones.  You want this instead:

```
y <- sub("1", "A", x)
y <- sub("2", "T", y)  # y, not x, is being acted on
y <- sub("3", "G", y)
y <- sub("4", "C", y)
```

Your 3rd version comes close to this, so it works.

For clearer style, I would change the loop too:

```
for (it in seq_along(rand1M)) {
  rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "1", replacement = "A", x = rand1M[it])
  rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "2", replacement = "T", x = rand1M[it])
  rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "3", replacement = "G", x = rand1M[it])
  rand1M[it] = sub(pattern = "4", replacement = "C", x = rand1M[it])
}
```

This way you don't have the mysterious variable `i`, and don't need to increment `it` yourself.

Comment: Thanks for that!I understand now, as sub() always produces an output independently of whether the condition was found or not, and in my case it is giving me the unchanged value of "i" and since it does not find that condition it reverts rand1M[it] into the number of "i".